# Merge two csv files based on common column

Tags: excel, openoffice.org

I have two csv files with data, which contains one common column with the same data (ex. product P/N that is unique).

How to merge all data into one spreadsheet?

**File one**

```
P/N | Name        | Quantity
xxx | Product xxx | 3
zzz | Product zzz | 6
yyy | Product yyy | 0
```

**File two**

```
P/N | Image
zzz | Image URL zzz
xxx | Image URL xxx
yyy | Image URL yyy
```

**What i want?**

```
P/N | Name        | Quantity | Image 
xxx | Product xxx | 3        | Image URL xxx
zzz | Product zzz | 6        | Image URL zzz
yyy | Product yyy | 0        | Image URL yyy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be to use VLOOKUP on the P/N in file one and grab the data from file two.

```
VLOOKUP(p/n,filetwotable,2,0)
```

drag this down to the bottom of column D, modify the third parameter (2) for the next two columns in columns E and F.

I would copy/paste special values to kill the formulas.

I do this often; I create a template then drop the data into it.

Good luck!

Comment: Finaly i understand this VLOOKUP function! :) Thanks